# Netbeans create/import cordova project from existing source

Tags: cordova, netbeans, cordova-3

Netbeans create/import cordova project from existing source?

I have netbeans 8.0, And created Cordova project from commandline, now
i want to open this project in Netbeans, But i don't see any option to import
existing source code and create cordova project from source.

Answer (score 7):

New Project -> HTML5 -> HTML5 Application with Existing Sources