# Building an existing Cordova app using Netbeans breaks up some of my plugins, how to set it up correctly?

Tags: cordova, netbeans-8, android-studio-2.2

I'm unable to find a detailed article online on how to setup an existing cordova app with netbeans. I used the "[HTML5 existing sources method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913022/netbeans-create-import-cordova-project-from-existing-source)" but it doesn't seem that netbeans build.xml is correctly built (which I could use some help doing).

What I know is that I have a working version of my cordova project using **Android Studio** but I don't know how to make it behave the same way in Netbeans (especially the build process).

**Specs:**

- MAC OSX
- Cordova 5.4.1
- Android Studio 2.2
- Netbeans 8.1
- Gradle 2.14 (using wrapper)

**Note:** Maybe my question is about what I need to copy from my Android Studio (Cordova) project to inside the nbproject folder to get things working correctly?

Comment: Where does the build process go wrong in Netbeans? Do you get a meaningful error message?

Comment: sometimes it does give errors, but mostly the run finishes successfully, yet I see (whether inside the app or through "Git status") that some plugins were broken (deleted, or reinstalled)...

Comment: my guess it has to do with using plugman tool to install plugins later in the project...but Android Studio understands that and doesn't break things like Netbeans!

Comment: How about removing your plugins and adding them again inside Netbeans? Would that work? I know it's sort of bypassing the problem, but it's probably a lot simpler than tinkering with the Netbeans files etc

Comment: I could try that, reluctantly! would you elaborate a little more on how to do that? I noticed netbeans' plugins.properties file has different structure than config.xml!

Comment: The following worked for me: 1) From the command line in your Cordova project directory: cordova rm plugin <plugin name>, do this for each of your plugins 2) from Netbeans: New project - HTML5 project with existing sources - select Cordova application, finish. 3) Right click your project in Netbeans - Properties - Cordova - plugins tab. Then add all your plugins from there.

Comment: that would work on native cordova plugins, I'm not sure about 3rd party plugins though. I'll try it anyway and get back to you.

Comment: for the record...no luck till now. the way of how netbeans structures cordova project is not the same as building cordova project on it's own..